# How to fetch the rows from SQL Server based on GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to fetch the rows from the top 2 pack id's not at a all of the rows in SQL Server?

Ex: Sample_table

```
tranid   packid referencenum
1         1      123456
2         1      654982
3         2      894652
4         3      684521
5         3      684651
6         4      987566
```

Based on above sample table, how do I get the rows of pack 2 (for 1 and 2) for next instance I need again 3 and 4 rows

Can anyone help me out to sort the issue?

Comment: Coiuld you make it clearer what you want as the result

Comment: Can you post a sample data for what you want your data to look like

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't miss something, this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PacksTable p
WHERE p.Id IN (1, 2)
```

Will give you only the data for the two `pack_id`'s in your table.

It is unclear what you are looking for here. You can group by `pack_id` then get the top two `pack_id`, but what do you want to do with the grouped `referencenum` values for grouped `pack_id`, i.e What aggregate function you will use for this column, `Min`, `Max`, etc ??!.

**In other words:** If you are looking for the `Top` minimum `pack_id`, i.e.: 1, 2 in the first time, you will have to answer the question: What aggregate function to use with the corresponding `referencenum` values??,

For example, you can use `MIN` like this:

```
SELECT TOP(2) p.packid, MIN(p.referencenum)
FROM PacksTable p
GROUP BY(p.packid)
ORDER BY p.packid
```

Answer (score 0):

please go through the following query.

```
select * from sample_table group by packid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use variables combined with the `DENSE_RANK` function to window through two packid's at a time:

```
create table #packing (tranid int,packid int,referencenum int)
insert into #packing values 
  (1,1,123456)
, (2,1,654982)
, (3,2,894652)
, (4,3,684521)
, (5,3,684651)
, (6,4,987566)
go

declare @i int=-1;
declare @j int=0;

while @@ROWCOUNT>0 begin
    set @i+=2;
    set @j+=2;
    ; with a as (
        select *, dr=dense_rank()over(order by packid) from #packing
    )
    select tranid, packid, referencenum 
    from a 
    where dr between @i and @j;
end
go

drop table #packing
go
```

Result:

[image]